# Laravel crashes at 10min import with error not related with the import

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing a massive import of around 50 excel files with PhpSpreadsheet and after 10 minutes Laravel crashes and returns the error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST.

This error is quite known and everyone knows what this means. However, **I don't do any request** in my import code process, much less a `GET` request. Also, if I import the content in short pieces (10 excels each time) it works just fine!

The import process overall takes around 30/40 minutes, but it always gets stuck at 10 minutes with that message error. My PHP ini is configured like this:

[image]

And all my import code is in a Try Catch:

```
try
{
    // Import process
} 
catch (\Exception $ex)
{
    \Log::error($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Still the `Try Catch` is unable to catch the error.

[image]

Also, it's worth saying that:

- Firstly the user uploads the 50 excels into the software (works fine)
- Then he presses a button to import the content of that 50 excels (error here)
- Some excels have 50k rows

What can I do to debug the problem and figure out what's wrong?

Comment: This sounds like something you should not handle through a webprocess, but through a decoupled shell process.

Comment: I was thinking about having 2 or 3 processes instead of just one...but I really would like to understand the error that is being shown to me, since I don't do any request while importing..

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is there anything written to your server's log files? To your application's log files? How is the server configured? Do these 10 minutes match the maximum execution time configured in PHP?

Comment: The error is raise from your route, not from your controller.

Comment: @NicoHaase 1. Improved the PHP ini; 2. No errors (not in the root nor in the storage/logs folder); they do not match, it's set for 3600 seconds (as you can see in the print)

Comment: What **else** have you tried to resolve the problem? If there is nothing logged, add some logging to your code and set a higher reporting level. As you haven't shared any code, its pretty difficult to see where your algorithm might go wrong

Comment: @NicoHaase I can't share the code since it's more than 2000 lines of code in the import process. Nothing related with `requests` though, only read info from excel > parse > save into database. I'm currently changing the code to split the import process in multiple requests instead of a single request.

Comment: Maybe "save into database" involves multiple calls of flush? Blackfire could help to check this

Comment: That could potentially be the problem. At some point I thought about inserting in bulk instead 1-by-1 but this would cause me to change too much code, since some files needs to check if the database already has certain value. I solved by spliting the processes, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

I couldn't find the cause of the error, since no error log was being created. In order to make it work, I split the import process in 5 processes instead of a single process.